# Java "finalize" thread on exception

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using several threads to do some heavy (and error-prone) processing on a large data set. I require all threads to finish execution, regardless of whether they throw an exception or terminate normally (no value is returned), before the program can continue. I am using a `CountDownLatch` to achieve this, and an `ExecutorService` to actually run the jobs. I want the worker threads (let's call them `JobManager`-s for the sake of argument) to notify the latch even if they throw an exception. A `JobManager` can take anywhere between a second and an hour to complete, and may fail at any time. The idea is to invoke the "finalizer" method of `JobManager` if an exception is thrown. Now, the `ExecutorService` likes to catch exceptions or to conceal the true origin of the ones it does not. I have though of a few ways around this, neither of which is satisfactory:

1. Use `ExecutorService#execute(Runnable r)` rather than `submit(Runnable r)`. I can do that since I do not care about the return value of the `JobManager`. I have provided a custom `ThreadFactory`, which attaches an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to each newly created thread. The problem with this approach is that when `UncaughtExceptionHandler#uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)` is invoked, `t`'s `Runnable` is of type `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker`, and not of type `JobManager`, which prevents me from invoking the "finalizer" method.
2. Use a custom `ExecutorService` and override the `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` method. This suffers from the same problem as 1.
3. Wrap the whole `JobManager#doWork()` in a `catch` statement and use the return value to indicate if an exception was thrown. I can then `submit` the jobs and use `FutureTask#get()` to decide if an exception was thrown. I do not like this solution because I feel return codes the wrong tool when you have an elaborate exception mechanism. Moreover, `get()` will wait (unless interrupted), which means I cannot handle errors in other threads immediately.
4. Get rid of the `CountDownLatch`. Store all `Future`s in a list and repeatedly poke in until I am satisfied with the states. This might work, but feels like a dirty hack.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful, but... +1 for really good formatting.

Comment: The idea really isn't to 'invoke the "finalizer" method of JobManager if an exception is thrown'. That's just one possible implementation. The idea is not to have finalize methods actually. I strongly suggest you rewrite your title to express your actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can use a simple `try`-`finally` block:

```
public class JobManager {
    public void doWork() {
        try {
            ...
        } finally {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```